# Referrer not blocked by htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to help a black funeral home stop harassment by a racist site.  One request they made was that I prevent direct linking from the racist site to theirs.

The following is the whole .htaccess

When I go to the harassing site (name not listed below as it contains racial slurs) and click one of their links to the funeral home I am never blocked.

What did I do wrong?

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

RewriteEngine On 
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} racistsitenamehere\.net [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} semalt\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule .* - [F] 


RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /page.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /page.php?page=$1&sub=$2 [L]


# block semalt
order allow,deny
deny from 85.58.23.115
deny from 177.21.203.170
allow from all
```

Comment: is the linking page served over https? Or is it using rel="noreferrer" in the link itself?

Comment: The page I am looking at is not served over https and the body of the link is `<a href="http://www.foobar.com.#sthash.3RddQ3s0.dpuf" target="_blank">www.foobar.com.#sthash.3RddQ3s0.dpuf</a>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing an `[OR]`, since the referer can't be BOTH (e.g. AND) of those, you want one or the other to be true:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} racistsitenamehere\.net [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} semalt\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Also wouldn't hurt to have an `L` flag in there.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I love StackOverflow!